# updating a parent record with child results

Tags: apex, trigger

Disclaimer:  This is my 2nd trigger ever as I work through the trailhead teachings.  2 questions: 1. how can I update the parent record since I already know the id of the account from the first

```
trigger sumContracts on CONTRACT (before update) {
for (Contract c : Trigger.new) {
    String id = '';

    // I Got the Account ID here

    List<Contract> acct = [SELECT Account.Id from Contract where Id =:c.Id];
    for(Contract a : acct){
        id = a.Account.Id;
    }

    //Get value of some fields

    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Total_Contract_Value__c) sum from Contract where ContractNumber='00000203'];

    //Covert it to a decimal, as a.Total_Contracts_Value__c is a currency field

    for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
        String sum = String.valueof(ar.get('sum'));
        Integer intCheck = Integer.ValueOf(sum);
        Decimal decVal = Decimal.ValueOf(intCheck);


    // Get the Account Id again because I am new to apex

        List<Account> accounts = [Select ID, Name From Account WHERE ID=:id];
        for(Account a : accounts){

                //Update the Total_Contracts_Value__c field in the parent Account
                a.Total_Contracts_Value__c = decVal;    ///    <---- Fails

                // As a test, update the description of this record with the value we want
                c.Description = String.valueof(decVal) + "," + a.Name;  /// <---- Success
        }
    }
  }
}
```

****Edit***

Based on the response, I think I have removed the loops problem I was creating.  I have successfully updated the parent record by doing so below.  Please feel free to offer advice on anything you see.

```
trigger sumContracts on CONTRACT (after update) {
for (Contract c : Trigger.new) {
    String id = '';
    Decimal decVal;

    List<Contract> acct = [SELECT Account.Id from Contract where Id =:c.Id];
    for(Contract a : acct){
        id = a.Account.Id;
    }

    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Total_Contract_Value__c) sum from Contract where Account.Id=:id];

    for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
        String sum = String.valueof(ar.get('sum'));
        Integer intCheck = Integer.ValueOf(sum);
        decVal = Decimal.ValueOf(intCheck);
    }
    //c.Description = String.valueof(decVal);

    Account myAccount = [Select ID, Name From Account WHERE ID=:id];
        myAccount.Total_Contracts_Value__c = decVal;
        update myAccount;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? Could you please be a bit more explicit about what behavior you observe or what you mean by "fails"?

Comment: The accounts total contracts value field is not getting updated.   When I do the test on contracts.description, that gets updated.

Comment: you are doing soql inside of a loop and your aggregate query doesn't make any sense as it is only looking at one record. I think you should use [edit] and define what business problem you are trying to solve

Comment: You should consider looking at the variety of tools which make rollup summaries configurable across lookups, such as `Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary` (DLRS) or `Rollup Helper`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things in your code which need fixing.

- Never consume any governors (such as queries, database operations,  etc) in a loop.
- Please read up on **[Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)** and understand what operations should be used when.

  > You can define triggers for top-level standard objects that support triggers, such as a Contact or an Account, some standard child objects, such as a CaseComment, and custom objects. To define a trigger, from the object management settings for the object whose triggers you want to access, go to Triggers.
  >   There are two types of triggers:
  >
  > - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
  > - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

  - Given that you are trying to do a *cross-object update*, that logic belongs always in the **`after`** context.

When you are in the `before` context and you set fields on context records (`trigger.new`), those changes persist to the database automatically. If you would like to update any other record, it should go in the `after` context and you then need to ***perform a DML operation on those records***.

```
switch on trigger.operationType
{
    WHEN AFTER_UPDATE
    {
        List<Account> relatedRecords = new List<Account>();
        // populate as needed

        update relatedRecords;
        // you should avoid "naked" DML operations like this
        // and instead wrap in a try/catch
        // make sure you NEVER use an empty catch block
        // and instead map the error back to the trigger context record which caused it
        // using the SObject.addError method
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant I will dig in further tomorrow. I truly appreciate the tesponse